# Python - passing regex result to a list

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, cad

I am trying to pass the results of a regex findall() function to a list. The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
#iterate DoL, find fobIDs and use to find edgeloop IDs
for key, val in DoL.items():
    fobId = val["FaceOuterBound"]
    edgeloop_txt = re.findall(r'\n#'+str(fobId)+r'\D*#(\d+).*;', text)
    edgeloops = [int(edgeloop) for edgeloop in edgeloop_txt]
    print(edgeloops)
```

The for loop is iterating through a dictionary and changing `fobId` each time, which is generating a different match each time. The output currently looks like this:

```
[159]
[328]
[37]
[18]
...
```

However, I want it to look like this instead:

```
[159, 328, 37, 18,....]
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the for loop changing the variable `edgeloop_txt` each time but I'm unsure of how to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are creating a new array and just printing it each time through the loop.  Try something like this:

```
total_array = []

for key, val in DoL.items():
    fobId = val["FaceOuterBound"]
    edgeloop_txt = re.findall(r'\n#'+str(fobId)+r'\D*#(\d+).*;', text)
    total_array += [int(edgeloop) for edgeloop in edgeloop_txt]
print(total_array)
```

This will loop through your items, continually adding to `total_array`, and print the entire array when the loop is complete.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!